# Specifying where to padx or pady?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout

Is it possible to specify where to apply the padding in Python Tkinter - like in CSS, there is `margin-[top|right|bottom|left]`?

There is `pady` but it inserts space *both* top and bottom. Same for `padx`, *both* left and right.

Comment: `padx` and `pady` are either a tuple of `(up, down)`/`(left, right)` or a single `int` to be used in both directions. Also do you want the padding to be inside the widget like the text in the button or do you want to padding to be around the widget?

Comment: In what I'm currently working at inside, but generally, to learn, also around. ----
I think padx and pady is space around the widget and ipadx/ipady is space inside the widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a `ttk` widget, you also have the option of setting the `padding` in the constructor for most widgets, which is synonymous with the `ipadx`, and `ipady` options.

It accepts the following patterns:

```
ttk.Button(padding=(5, 10, 5, 10))      # (left, right, top, bottom)
ttk.Button(padding=((5, 10), (5, 10)))  # ((left, right), (top, bottom))
ttk.Button(padding=(5, 10))             # (left/right, top/bottom)
ttk.Button(padding=5)                   # left/right/top/bottom
```

For `padx` and `pady`, the following patterns are acceptable:

```
padx=(5, 10)  # (left, right)
padx=5 # left & right

pady=(5, 10)  # (top, bottom)
pady=5  # top & bottom
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible with the `item.grid(padx=20, pady=80)` if this provide the wanted results you can always use the `item.place(x, y)` instead.